# Page does not scroll up when dragging an element to top with fixed navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have elements on a page that needs to be draggable to the top or bottom of the page - if there is a long list of elements, the page should automatically scroll up or down while dragging the elements.

I find no issue with scrolling when dragging an element from the top to the bottom of the page, however, if the element that I want to drag is from the bottom to the top, I found that the fixed top navigation bar does not allow the page to scroll up.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L_Diaz/z5jbL9vf/1/)

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: -25px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="App">
      <h1>This is a fixed navbar</h1>
      <p>item</p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
      <p draggable="true">
        Draggable paragraph. Page should scroll when you drag up or down
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to see first if there is a way to fix this in HTML / CSS, if not, in JavaScript.

Comment: You linked an empty codesandbox?

Comment: update sandbox link

Comment: Hi, I tried the link on different browsers even when I'm logged out and it's working.

Comment: ok, what do you want to do by making things draggable? what do you mean by that can you explain please

Comment: There is no problem dragging the elements that have the "draggable" attribute. The issue it that the page does not scroll up when I am dragging the bottom most element to the top.

Comment: Because they are simple text controlled by para tag. When maybe you are trying to do that they were copying. You need to modify their properties

Comment: @L.Diaz WHAT you are using. There is class name. Is that you are working with react

Comment: I am working with HTML, CSS, JavaScript. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: they are still draggable

Comment: select then try to move them they are not buttons or something like that. Try to understand they are text they need to be selected first then only they will be able to move

Comment: there is NO PROBLEM dragging. THE PROBLEM: The page does not SCROLL when you drag from bottom to top

Comment: sorry but I tried and they did. What's your goal what you want to do what you are thinking. I'm not in front of you so it's hard to understand maybe I have the solution but I am unable to understand your concern

Comment: Select some text and holding the click try to move down you will be able to scroll with them.

Comment: I think they are now as you want them @L.Diaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is sample code with fixed top, right and left navs and a centre container that can scroll. The important things to note are the heights give to each element.
The reason it does not scroll in your sample code is because the top and the bottom of the draggable container are not on top of the view port which can trigger the scroll event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: green;
            }
            
            .sticky {
              padding: 0 16px;
              background: #555;
              color: #f1f1f1;
              position: fixed;
              top: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 80px;
              
            }
            .parent-container {
                width: inherit;
                height: inherit;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background-color: pink;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .container-con{
            position: static;  
              overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 100%;
          }
          .container{
            position: relative; 
            top:80px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: calc(100% - 82px);
            border: 1px solid red;
          }
          .container > div {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
          }
          .left-nav{
            position: fixed; 
            width: 100px;
          }
          .center-nav{
            margin-left: 100px;
            width: 250px;
            height: calc(100% - 10px);
            overflow-y: scroll;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            
          }
          .right-nav{
            width: 100px;
            position: fixed; 
            right: 0;

          }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="parent-container">
            <div class="sticky">
              <h1>My Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="container-con">
            <div class="container" >
                <div class="left-nav">
                  Left nav
                </div>
                <div class="center-nav">                            
                  <div draggable="true">draggable start <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 4 <br><br></div>


                  <div draggable="true">draggable 1 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 4 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 1 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 4 <br><br></div>

                  <div draggable="true">draggable 1 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 4 <br><br></div>

                  <div draggable="true">draggable 1 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 4 <br><br></div>

                  <div draggable="true">draggable 1 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 4 <br><br></div>

                  <div draggable="true">draggable 1 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 4 <br><br></div>

                  <div draggable="true">draggable 1 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 4 <br><br></div>

                  <div draggable="true">draggable 1 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 2 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable 3 <br><br></div>
                  <div draggable="true">draggable end <br><br></div>
                </div>
                 <div class="right-nav">
                  right nav
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, is it me or on your sample we can not scroll with the mouse wheel while doing drag and drop?

Comment: works for me not sure.

Comment: I can't neither

Comment: which browser are you trying it on?

Comment: There is a very narrow zone, when hovering over it the container scrolls. But dragging past this zone the container doesn't scroll anymore, which in my opinion makes it working worse than the example in the question.